# Import and use Google SignIn iOS SDK in a Swift Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, google-signin

I need to import [`Google/SignIn SDK`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn) in a swift framework `MySDK` which is used in `MyApp` and I'm not quite sure how to do that. I use CocoaPods as a dependency manager.

Here is some background:

#### Main app

If I wanted to use `Google/SignIn` in the main `MyApp`, I would need to include the following line in the `MyApp-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
```

That would allow me to `import Google` in any swift file and use it, no problem.

#### Dynamic framework

Dynamic frameworks don't have bridging headers, so I tried to put in the umbrella header `MySDK.h`. However, this produces the following error:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MySDK'
```

Although not importing `<Google/SignIn.h>` allows `MySDK` to build successfully and use Google SDK throughout the framework, when I try to import `MySDK` in `MyApp`, I get the following error on the `import MySDK` line:

```
MyApp/ViewController.swift:10:8: Missing required module 'Google'
```

[image: Screen Shot - Missing required module Google]

What's interesting is that I have this problem only with Google SDK. All the other dependencies, like [`Facebook LoginKit`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKLoginKit) work without any issues.

#### GitHub repo demostrating the issue

https://github.com/tomaskraina/GoogleSDK-in-dynamic-framework

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. This may be a trick but it worked for me i explicitly installed Google/SignIn pod in my main project too, doing this provided the main project the dependency it was unable to locate and thus I was able to use my dynamic framework.